# Passing State To Child Component is null on button press

Tags: reactjs

Newby React Project Help:

I am trying to pass the state of a component to a child component so it can load an image. The state of gift1 is null originally. When a button is pressed, it toggle displays the child component and gift1 is set to an object with details of an image. Below is the toggle set up in the parent component where this.state.giftContainer is used to toggle the child component: GiftBoxAnimation. It also passes the gift1 state as gift property to the child.

```
let display = this.state.giftContainer && this.state.giftContainer === true 
  ? (<GiftBoxAnimation gift={this.state.gift1} />)
  : null;
```

When a button in the parent component is pressed, `generateItems()` fires and sets the state of gift1 to that object and then toggles the child

```
  generateItems = (e) =>{
  //Insert code here that sets state of gift1: {name: "giftImage"}

    this.setState({
      giftContainer: true
    });
  }
```

The Child Component looks something like this:

```
  <Spritesheet
    className={"sprite-gift"}
    image={"/images/"+this.props.gift+".png"}
    widthFrame={1024}
    heightFrame={1024}
    steps={5}
    fps={5}
    autoplay={true}
    loop={true}
  />
```

When I try and get the image data using `this.props.gift`, it returns gift1 null state originaly set. The second time the button on the parent component is pressed, an Object is return. However, if I try and access the image with 
`this.props.gift.name` It is `undefined`.

How can I pass the parent state to the child, so I can display the image in the child component on the first button press of the parent?

Comment: Errors of first and second button press: [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/fwkpYZYJ5zebetNHA)

Comment: `console.log(gift)` in the render function or debug it. Its looks like an issue with the structure as the name that is passed in going in as an object.

Comment: When ```console.log(this.props.gift)```I get {}, then {name: "image-name"}, so it does return the object eventually, however it is only displaying the {} in the image property of the Spritesheet so no image is appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following code to pass an empty object if null

```
let display = this.state.giftContainer 
&& this.state.giftContainer === true 
?(<GiftBoxAnimation gift={this.state.gift1 || {}}/>)
:(null);
```

Comment: With what you suggested, I am now getting the object. However, in the child, when I access the "name" property of the object for the first time, it returns undefined. Why is this? The second time I press the button an image successfully loads

Comment: Your original question was how to avoid the error. So this code solves that error.  empty object got no `name` property hence `undefined`. `this.state.gift1 || {name: 'default-image-name'}` will get rid of that undefined

Comment: [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/WFptM1ZeXkqk6Kzz7) This what I Get on the first button press. For some reason, the child is only trying to change the image of the first returned prop, which is the default, but I need it to change it to "moonskelly" which is randomly generated from the parent. The second button press and on work fine, I just need the first one to work

Comment: The Issue was that I was calling a setState synchronously. Your answer does fit the issue I suggested originally, Thanks!